# Is there a way to create multiple HTML and use same bundle for every html in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

I'm trying to create different html using webpack.

```
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: {
          loader: "html-loader"
        }
      }
```

This will generate the html during building, but for some reason CSS is not working for those .html (excluding `index.html` where its working`).

Comment: `html-loader`'s purpose is so you can load html, for example with `import html from './file.html';`. then you can `console.log(html); // "<html>..."` or whatever in your script. While you indirectly can use it to generate new html files, that is not the task of html-loader.  Maybe you are thinking about `html-webpack-plugin`? https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

You can use more than one `html-webpack-plugin` for that.

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
// ...
module.exports = {
    // ...
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: {
                    loader: "html-loader"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        //...
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './views/index1.html',
            filename: 'index1.html',
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './views/index2.html',
            filename: 'index2.html',
        }),
        //..
    ]
};
```